# Texto retornando com "?" no lugar de aspas e hifens

Tags: php, codificação-de-caracteres

Boa tarde.

Meu site roda na codificação ISO-8859-1 e quando puxo dados de um XML externo, alguns caracteres retornam como uma interrogação.

Tentei converter com `<?php header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); ?>` mas todo o restante do site como o topo, rodapé e outras áreas sofreram com a troca da codificação.

Também já adicionei o utf8_decode() e nada resolveu.

Alguém conhece alguma solução para o problema?

Um link de exemplo https://api.dino.com.br/v2/news/118219/mundo-do-marketing

```
<?php
                $arquivo = "https://api.dino.com.br/v2/news/$id/mundo-do-marketing";

                $info = file_get_contents($arquivo);

                $lendo = json_decode($info);

                echo '<pre>' . print_r($lendo, true) . '</pre>';

                echo $lendo->Item->Summary;

                $titulo = utf8_decode($lendo->Item->Title);
                $autor = utf8_decode($lendo->Item->Author);
                $retranca = utf8_decode($lendo->Item->Summary);
                $data = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($lendo->Item->PublishedDate));
                $categoria = utf8_decode($lendo->Item->Categories[0]->Name);
                $conteudo = utf8_decode($lendo->Item->Body);

                if($id == 108988){
                    redirect(base_url('noticias-corporativas'));
                }

                else{
            ?>

                    <h2><?php echo $titulo; ?></h2>
                    <p class="retranca-dino"><?php echo $retranca; ?></p>
                    <p class="autor-dino">Categoria: <span class="autor"><?php echo $categoria; ?></span></p>
                    <p class="autor-dino">Autor: <span class="autor"><?php echo $autor; ?></span></p>
                    <span class="data-dino">Data de Publicação: <span style="font-weight: normal;"><?php echo $data; ?></span></span>

                <?php
                        if(empty($lendo->Item->Image->Url)){
                            echo NULL;
                        }

                        else{

                            $imagem = $lendo->Item->Image->Url;
                ?>
                        <div class="imagem-dino">
                            <img class="imagem" src="<?php echo $imagem; ?>" alt="<?php echo $titulo; ?>" title="<?php echo $titulo; ?>" />
                        </div>

                <?php
                        }
                    }
                ?>

                <div class="conteudo-dino"><?php echo $conteudo; ?></div>

            <?php
                echo br(1);
            ?>
```

Att.

Comment: já tentou `mb_convert_encoding($texto, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8')`?

Comment: deoliveiralucas não funcionou, continua retornando como interrogação.

Comment: Como você obtém esses dados do XML externo? Posta ai na pergunta.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta

Comment: Uma coisa que eu notei é que o formato das aspas são diferentes, deixa eu tentar explicar. Meio que uma hora são arredondadas e outra hora é normal como no teclado, será que não estão cadastrando conteúdo com texto misto?

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo a documentação do PHP você deveria utilizar a função utf8_encode. Olha o que diz a documentação: utf8_encode — Codifica um string ISO-8859-1 para UTF-8. Veja se soluciona.

Comment: Eu já tinha feito isso e continua dando o mesmo problema. Uma coisa que eu notei é que o formato das aspas são diferentes, deixa eu tentar explicar.

Meio que uma hora são arredondadas e outra hora é normal como no teclado, será que não estão cadastrando conteúdo com texto misto?

Comment: Vi ali que você utilizou json_decode(). Já tentou utilizar a função simplexml_load_file() ?

Comment: Já tentei da erro

Answer (score 0):

Simulei o seu erro aqui. O que provavelmente está acontecendo é que mesmo seu site rodando em ISO, o file_get_contents já está pegando a codificação UTF-8.

As três alternativas para arrumar:

1.Tire os utf8_decode:

```
$conteudo = $lendo->Item->Body;
```

2.Complemente a primeira(tirando os utf8_decode)  adicionando um:

```
ini_set( 'default_charset', 'utf-8');
```

3. Apenas adicione essa linha(mantenha o resto como está no seu código):

   ini_set( 'default_charset', 'iso-8859-1');

Comment: Eu adiciono essa linha ini_set( 'default_charset', 'iso-8859-1'); em qual parte do código? Antes da variável $titulo?

Comment: Adicionei essa linha no começo do meu arquivo, um dos problemas que acontece é que inverte o problema para outras áreas da página. Outros caracteres especiais que rodavam no ISO passaram a ficar com uma interrogação dentro de um losango preto

Comment: Tentou a primeira alternativa?

Comment: Sim Rodrigo, cheguei a tentar as 3 soluções. O problema que outras partes da página ficam com caracteres quebrados.

Comment: Se o problema inverte um workarround, é dar um ini_set de novo quando terminar.